# Cannot EFI boot from Clonezilla disk image

Tags: linux, ubuntu, grub, efi, clonezilla

I have created a Ubuntu Server 14.04 system that I would like to clone to several other machines with exactly the same hardware specifications. The system is an Intel NUC2820 with 30 GB SSD.

The current working installation contains three partitions:

```
/sda1 fat32 (efi boot)
/sda2 ext4
/sda3 swap
```

The system is set up using GPT and uses UEFI for boot.

With Tuxboot I created a **CloneZilla** USB and wrote the complete disk to an image that I would like to use to restore. However after restoring the image to a new machine I can't seem to find a way to make the system bootable again.

I tried using **grub-install** from the CloneZilla environment, but I get the following error:

```
warning : this GPT partition label contains no  BIOS boot Partition; embedding wont be possible
warning : Embedding id not possible. GRUB can only be installed in this setup by using blocklists. However, blocklists are UNRELIABLE and their use is discouraged..
error : will not proceed with blocklists
```

I guess this has something to do with grub not working in EFI mode. I have no idea if I can force grub to create an EFI partition. When I use **efibootmgr** i get the message:

```
efi variables are not supported on this system
```

I also tried to use the Ubuntu 14.04 Server installer, but re-installing Grub in rescue mode says:

```
executing 'grub-install' failed
This is a fatal error
```

When i execute **grub-install** from the shell I get the a message the Grub is successfully installed 
, although still can't find a boot disk upon start up.

Is there any way to get the image to be bootable again

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After days of searching of course I find the answer myself an hour after I decided to post here.

Using a [Ubuntu-based](http://clonezilla.org/downloads/download.php?branch=alternative) version of CloneZilla I got it to boot in UEFI-mode which was able to update the correct boot records.

Comment: So the ubuntu uefi clonezilla worked out of the box?  Or you had to boot and repair the new image?

Comment: Yes, it worked out of the box. I created an image from the Ubuntu install and wrote this to another machine. I did not had to update or fix any of the boot records.

Comment: I had the exact same experience with an UEFI Intel NUC. An older non-ubuntu Clonezilla woudn't restore the image properly. The same image restored (and booted) just fine when I used the newer Ubuntu specific Clonezilla.